# problems with using count

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out what type of membership which is the type_id has with a count of cars that have this membership

Here are my tables

```
create table car_hire
(car_id char (5)  primary key not null,
car_reg varchar (15) not null,
car_make varchar (20) not null,
car_model varchar (20) not null,
car_year date not null,
type_id char (5) not null)
engine=innodb;

create table car_type
(type_id   char(4) primary key not null,
type_decription varchar (15) not null,
Hire_cost int (5) not null)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Please help

Comment: Can you post an example of queries you've tried but didn't work? Us doing your homework/job/whatever-else-it-is for you doesn't really help in the long term, but helping you understand how to do it is better all-round.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.type_id, count(*)
from car_type t left join car_hire h on t.type_id = h.type_id
group by t.type_id
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! it worked! I'm very new to sql so i'm still trying to understand it. I tried
SELECT Car_id, COUNT(type_description) as "number of cars"
FROM car_type,car_hires
where car_id
GROUP BY type_description

which came up with something but didn't do the trick ;-(
Is there a website that explains queries in full?

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
SELECT type_id, COUNT(*)
FROM car_hire
GROUP BY type_id
```